# Visual Studio 2013 Analyze Code Code Coverage TestInitialize database file exists

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage, dbcontext, integration-testing

Please can any one advise me on an issue I am having? I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting in a C# project in Visual Studio 2013.

I have unit tests which spin up a new database instance in the TestInitialise method using a DbContextInitialiser which inherits from DropCreateDatabaseAlways

If I "Run All" tests then the tests pass fine. If I try to "Anaylize Code Coverage" for all tests, tests start to fail with error messages indicating the .mdf file already exists. It should drop and recreate the database for each test, however I assume the tests are run asynchronously so a file lock developes.

Please advise what is my best course of action. Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Duane.

Comment: Note that since you are dropping and recreating the db, these are not Unit test, these are Integration tests.

Comment: Also is .mdf file part of your solution? Do you have this added as a [DeploymentItems]?

Comment: @Spock - Thanks for the clarification on what type of tests they are. I assumed they were tests that unit-tesing the methods in my repositories.

I do not have the .mdf added as [DeploymentItems]. They are created and destroyed on demand for each test using 
`// Set db initialiser to create an empty database
var initialiser = new WebsiteDbContextInitialiser();
Database.SetInitializer(initialiser);
initialiser.InitializeDatabase(_unitOfWork);`